# Word or expression for a child who looks exactly like a parent

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What word or expression can I use for a baby who is the exact copy of one of its parents?

Comment: "He is a **[dead ringer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dead_ringer)** for his dad".

Comment: Or, if we are speaking about a person's behaviour or character, "He is a **[chip off the old block](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chip_off_the_old_block)**"

Comment: An _exact_ copy? That would be a **clone**. ;^)

Comment: @J.R. - even a clone *[would not be an exact copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigenetics)*. (0:

Answer (score 15):

One such phrase is [the spitting image.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spitting+image)

Comment: Colloquially (in BrE, at least), you can also say *He's the [dead] spit of his father*. It says [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22then+became+spitting+image%22) *In the early nineteenth century it was possible to describe a child as 'the spit' of his father, or for emphasis the 'spit and image'. This could also appear as 'spitten image', which then became 'spitting image'.* But I don't accept that plain old ***spit*** is no longer used.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting.  In America, "the spitting image" is far more  common.  I don't think I've ever heard anyone say "the dead spit" before!

Comment: As above; "the spit of", "dead spit" or "spitting image". "Double" is also popular i.e. "he's his double".

Comment: +1 Another American English speaker for *the spitting image*. I've never heard of 'he's his double' to refer to parent child-resemblance.

Comment: I believe it comes from "spi'it 'n image" (an abbreviated form of "spirit and image").

Comment: @Abs I've never heard "dead spit" either, but: "Dead" sometimes means "exact" (dead right, dead wrong, dead-on, dead reckoning) and "spit" comes from "spi'it" or "spirit."

Answer (score 9):

Like others have said, **the spitting image** and **dead ringer** are good ones to describe family members who look *exactly* alike.  **Carbon copy** is my personal favorite.  "He is a carbon copy of his dad!"

You could perhaps use *duplicate*, *look-alike*, *twin* or *doppelganger* depending on what you're going for.  Some words would work better for strangers rather than relatives though (ex. "you two could be twins!" or "she's his doppelganger, I swear" or "she's an exact duplicate of him").

Here are some [synonyms for *spitting image*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/spitting%20image) that you might find useful.

Comment: I agree the _doppelganger_ works better for strangers than relatives, but I'm still upvoting this answer on account of that suggestion. That's a great word for leaners.

Comment: What's great about carbon copy is that he is indeed a carbon based life form!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is quite recent, but many people will recognize [Mini-Me](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mini-Me) as an exact (although smaller) copy of someone.

Answer (score 1):

While not strictly about appearance, some common phrases having to do with parental similarities are

- A chip off the old block
- The apple doesn't fall far from the tree

Comment: I've always interpreted these saying as more about how the child behaves than how they look.

Comment: I agree with @ColleenV.  Those are related to personality traits rather than looks.